# Investigating XMLWriter object

Tags: c#, silverlight

How can I see the XML contents of fully populated `XmlWriter` object while debugging. My silverlight application doesn't permit to actually write to a file and check the contents.

Comment: You could write your XML to a `MemoryStream`, and e.g. read it back from there into a string (using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the XmlWriter based on a MemoryStream, then unencode the bytes from the memory stream and display it in a text box, for example.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
ws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, ws);
// populate the writer
w.Flush();
textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Position);
```

Comment: In Silverlight, yes, but in different platforms it's not defined, so I'd rather be explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Have it write to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x972ksd0.aspx) or [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66dybzaw.aspx) instead of a file. That will allow you to check the output.

Answer (score 0):

An `XmlReader` is not "populated". It represents the state of an XML parsing operation, as that operation is in progress. This state will change as the XML is read.