# Investigating XMLReader object

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180726/investigating-xmlwriter-object) about how to investigate the contents of `XMLWriter` object while debugging.
I am trying to check the contents of an `XmlReader` object that is created from a memory stream in a similar way as given in the answer of the linked question. But I am getting `UnauthorizedAccessException` stating `MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed.` How to verify the xml read from the MemoryStream?

```
public PInfo(byte[] pBytes)
{   
    MemoryStream pMem  = new MemoryStream(pBytes);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(pMem);

      //MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed.  
      string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pMem.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)pMem.Position); 
      ....

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the MSDN Docs for the particular constructor you're using, [`MemoryStream(Byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx). When you instantiate it this way, `GetBuffer()` will throw that exception, since the buffer is not actually visible. You should instead use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y0t45kk.aspx), and be sure to set `publiclyVisible` to `true`.

Comment: `MemoryStream pMem = new MemoryStream(pBytes, 0, pBytes.Length, true, true);` did the trick. Thanks!!!